# C++/C Как запустить консольное приложение с параметрами без консоли

Tags: c++, c, консоль

Есть у меня задача:

> нужно запустить консольное приложение(имеютcя исходники приложения) прямо в моем написанном приложении и также надо уметь его закрывать.

Так, теперь более подробно:

Допустим, у нас есть исходный код консольного приложения, которое может запускаться из консоли с параметрами. Я пишу свое, также консольное, приложение, но оно из консоли запускаться не будет, так вот, как мне "вшить" это приложение в свое так, чтобы я мог его как запускать так и закрывать, все также, из своего приложения.

Решения по типу "Используй уже собранное приложение и CreateProcess с параметрами" не подходят.

Comment: По какой причине не подходит нечто типа `CreateProcess`?

Comment: Дело в том, что мне надо именно сорцы этого приложения всторить в свое приложение и запускать его именно из моего приложение с моими параметрами.

Comment: @Aleksei.C Вы определитесь с тем, что вам надо: запустить стороннее консольное приложение или встроить функционал этого приложения? Если второе, то не понятно, что вам мешает, имея на руках все сорцы.

Comment: @zed. Если не понимаете, что конкретно мне надо сделать перечитайте пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aleksei.C это не причина, это просто желание. Но в целом нет ничего сложного объединить несколько исходников в один проект. Сложности начнутся при необходимости инициализации, освобождения глобальных ресурсов.

Comment: @Aleksei.C Вы ставите взаимоисключающие требования в своём вопросе. Без использования CreateProcess и контроля потоков ввода/вывода невозможно запустить консольное приложение "без консоли". Именно использование CreateProcess и даёт вам ПОЛНЫЙ контроль над запущенным процессом. Вот [пример](https://bitbucket.org/zedxxx/sdb_util/src/afdc040668d728f10f61eaf3ef861df753e5c965/src/u_ConsoleAppRunner.pas) моего кода (там Delphi, но суть не меняется), при помощи которого я в GUI-шном приложении вызываю консольные утилитки, не пугая юзера консолью.

Comment: @zed. Я просто наверно не совсем верно выразился. Мне нужно внедрить сорцы чужого приложения в свое и вызывать это внедренное приложение уже из своего со всеми параметрами, без использования CreateProcess. Так понятнее?

Comment: Проблема добавить исходники в проект или в чем конкретно?

Comment: @Aleksei.C Если у вас цель использовать функционал через сорцы, то ни о каком "*запустить*" или "*закрыть*" и речи быть не может. Всё, что вы можете, это **вызывать** функции с определёнными параметрами. Т.е. ваш вопрос нужно переформулировать: "Как мне вызвать функции стороннего приложения, имея на руках исходники этого приложения". И после такой формулировки к вам возникает вопрос - вы не знаете как подключить эти исходники чтобы они скомпилировались с вашим проектом и не понимаете, какие функции надо вызывать?

Comment: Нет, проблем с подключением исходников у меня нету. Воотщем объясню всю проблему. Имеется у меня 5 майнинг ферм, которые находятся в 500 км от меня. Я пишу софт которым по моему мнению будет удобно управлять этими фермами, использую майнер XMRig https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig и мне надо понять как туда так сказать "Перманентно вшить параметры пулов, юзера, доп. параметры и тд", а далее вызывать функцию с параметрами. Ну вообщем не подумайте, что я там какой нибудь школьник которому скрытые майнеры в кайф распространять. Ну вообщем как-то так.

Answer (score 4):

Наверное, проще всего будет переименовать функцию main() того приложения, что надо "встроить"  в любое допустимое имя и просто вызывать эту функцию с нужными параметрами.

Comment: Спасибо попробую!